# Is the space $X$ is complete?(TRue/False)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map between metric spaces. Then $f(X)$ is a complete subset of $Y$ if

1. the space $X$ is compact
2. the space $Y$ is compact
3. the space $X$ is complete
4. the space $Y$ is complete

My trial :   i was taking $X =Y =R$,,and i know that R is complete as complete map to complete  so the correct option will option 3 that is the space X is complete .

Is my answer is correct or not ? pliz verified and tell me the solution  i would be more thankful...

Comment: 2. It's not true. You can take $f:(0,1) \rightarrow [0,1]$, whence $f$ is identity function.

Comment: why donvote....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is compact too and therefore complete.

All other options are false. Can you see why?

Comment: after many days@ Jose carlos santos,,,,,my doubt is that  how can u claim that X is compact ,,,as i was thinking about R because R is complete  ,,,,,as why i cannot take R ?

Comment: @lomberlego How can **I** claim that $X$ is compact? That's what's written in item number 1: “the space $X$ is compact”. I don't understand your other question.

Comment: as from ur answer (last  3 week)  i know something about compactness,,that it map  compact to compact....so option 1 is correct...but now  my question is that   why option  3 is not correct ? can u give me counter example ..im not able to see option 3 answer.

Comment: @lomberlego Sure: $\exp\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. It's image is $(0,+\infty)$, which is not complete.

Comment: .@ jose carlos santos i take  f(x)= e^-x....is it right ?

Comment: @lomberlego No. I took $f(x)=e^x$. But $f(x)=e^{-x}$ will also do.

Comment: Now i got it deeply @ Jose Carlos santos,,,, thanks  a lots